# Comparison of stability of aromatic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry

What is the basis of comparison between two aromatic compounds having different ring structures
Like in propyl and heptyl rings

Comment: There is no point in comparing the stability of two entirely different things.

Comment: Do you mean comparing how much "aromaticity" it has? The degree of aromaticity can be evaluated either through computations or hydrogenations; it represents how much more stable a compound is due to aromaticity (and thus how much more energy it takes to hydrogenate it compared to an "equivalent" non aromatic compound)

Comment: To put Ivan's comment differently, how do you compare the stability of an electron and the stability of nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take ring strain into account. If you analyze the energy of an organic cycle as a function of the number of atoms in the ring, you find out that cyclohexane and cyclopentane rings are most stable, because the internal angles of an hexagon (120°) and a pentagon (108°) are closer to the angle in a tetrahedron (109°28').